# How is the function defined in jquery ready function executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I use the follwing statement in the console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jquery working");
});
```

Then the alert is displayed. But If I do the following in plain javascript as:

```
( function() { alert("Without jquery") } );
```

Then this expression is treated simply as a function defintion and alert is not displayed. So, why in jquery a function defintion is converted to a function call?

Comment: `.ready` is a method which is being invoked as we are wrapping it with parenthesis(`()`)... `( function() { alert("Without jquery") } )();` will work!

Comment: you can do this: `( function() { alert("Without jquery") } )();` but this will be executed immediately when interpretted by the javascript interpreter, usually when the page is loading, not after the dom is ready.

Comment: @orhor But that is an Immediately invoked function expression. In jquery they aren't using parenthesis `()` after function expression

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "in jQuery"? .ready is a function which is executed immediately it is interpretted. Internally it only registers the content, your function with alert() to a collection of functions they ought to be executed when particular event is fired - dom ready in this case. when this event is fired, jQuery listens and as a reaction executes all registered functions, one of them is your function with alert. similarly it works for all event handlers

Comment: I mean in jquery code I have written in my question.

Comment: yeah, so hopefully it was explained

Comment: @orhor How does ready function convert the function definitions into function calls?

Comment: it does not, internally it holds just referencies to those functions, those referencies are passed as parameters. imagin such model: `function myFunc(param){param();}` in this very simple model myFunc expects a function as a parameter and once executed it executes the parameter. jQuery works in similar manner, it just executes a function which was passed as parameter. your function with alert was passed as a parameter to a ready() function

Comment: @user31782  read is a function which is invoked as soon as the dom is ready i.e as soon as the DOM structure is loaded which is just the tags (if you can say) without actually loading the contents within the elements hence DOM gets ready as soon as you hit the url/refresh (well if the page has very few elements)

Comment: @orhor I got what you say. `ready(){}` function takes other function as its parameters and calls the parameter when the ready function is itself called. I am asking how does jquery implements this in it's source code? Does it simply define ready functiuon as `ready(param) { param(); }`?

Comment: no as simple, you have to take the logic of a handlers collection into account, there can be tens of ready() usage in a single page, ready() can be used even after the page is fully loaded, for example in ajax completed handler you use ready() and it should work the way you experince when calling it from the console........., another thing is the scope under which is the handler executed etc,etc,etc.... you can of course download jQuery and look in the code yourself ;)